# how to solve double quotes issue in facebook og title property

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a simple open graph functionality on my facebook app and I post some dynamic text on facebook. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# APP: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/APP#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="00000000000000" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="XXX:XXX" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="http://example.com" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="<?php echo $_GET['title']; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:description" content=" " /> 
  <meta property="og:image"       content="<?php echo $_GET['image']; ?>" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
```

The problem is that when there are double quotes inside $_GET['title'] variable only the part before that quote is sent to facebook. I know why this happens but can't think of any solution to this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks David. But your solution created problems with accentuated characters (é è ...) so I tried `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['title'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>` and it worked better for me

Comment: By the way, it seems facebook doesn't like the double quotes anyway. In every share popup I came across, the text after the first double quote is stripped away, even if properly entity encoded. Infact I suggested my authors to use single quotes or the «double angle quotation marks»

Comment: Even using the debugger [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) it shows it doesn't fetch the text after the first double quotes character.

Comment: From a security point of view, you should also be escaping all the `echo $_GET`s to prevent people from injecting JavaScript into your page and attacking your users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<?php echo htmlentities($_GET['title'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>` should work?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has faced same issue with other programming language, just replace `"` to `&quot;`
For example using python:

```
title = post.title.replace('"', '&quot;')
```